# Only change class in this scope

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a card which has `onclick` change functionality.

If I include two of these cards on my page, the classes will duplicate. But it's also changing the class in the second card when a change occurs in the first and vice versa.

Here is a demo:

```js
$('div[data-item="item--1"]').addClass('active');


  $('.header').click(function() {
    var myEm = $(this).attr('data-item');
    $('.header, .subheader').removeClass('active');
    $('.header[data-item = '+myEm+'], .subheader[data-item = '+myEm+']').addClass('active');
  });
```

```css
.card{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 30px;
  background: lightblue;
}

.headers{
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.header{
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.header.active{
  opacity: 1;
}

.subheader{
  display: none;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}



.header.active,
.subheader.active{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="card">
  <div class="headers">
    <div class="header" data-item="item--1">Test</div>
    <div class="header" data-item="item--2">Test 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="subheaders">
    <div class="subheader" data-item="item--1">Subheader for Test</div>
    <div class="subheader" data-item="item--2">Subheader for Test 2</div>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="card">
  <div class="headers">
    <div class="header" data-item="item--1">Another Test</div>
    <div class="header" data-item="item--2">Another Test 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="subheaders">
    <div class="subheader" data-item="item--1">Subheader for Another Test</div>
    <div class="subheader" data-item="item--2">Subheader for Another Test 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the closest `.card` ancestor as the context of the selectors.

```
$('.header').click(function() {
    var myEm = $(this).attr('data-item');
    $('.header, .subheader', $(this).closest('.card')).removeClass('active');
    $('.header[data-item = '+myEm+'], .subheader[data-item = '+myEm+']', 
      $(this).closest('.card')).addClass('active');
});
```

Live Example:

```js
$('div[data-item="item--1"]').addClass('active');


  $('.header').click(function() {
    var myEm = $(this).attr('data-item');
    $('.header, .subheader', $(this).closest('.card')).removeClass('active');
    $('.header[data-item = '+myEm+'], .subheader[data-item = '+myEm+']', $(this).closest('.card')).addClass('active');
  });
```

```css
.card{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 30px;
  background: lightblue;
}

.headers{
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.header{
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.header.active{
  opacity: 1;
}

.subheader{
  display: none;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}



.header.active,
.subheader.active{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="card">
  <div class="headers">
    <div class="header" data-item="item--1">Test</div>
    <div class="header" data-item="item--2">Test 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="subheaders">
    <div class="subheader" data-item="item--1">Subheader for Test</div>
    <div class="subheader" data-item="item--2">Subheader for Test 2</div>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="card">
  <div class="headers">
    <div class="header" data-item="item--1">Another Test</div>
    <div class="header" data-item="item--2">Another Test 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="subheaders">
    <div class="subheader" data-item="item--1">Subheader for Another Test</div>
    <div class="subheader" data-item="item--2">Subheader for Another Test 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```